# PHP - How to solve message notification error “using $this when not in object context”?

Tags: php, pdo

Hello please am having a problem with my message sending notification in PHP PDO and 
below is my code for addMention sendNotification if someone mentions a user in his post.

```
public function addMention($status,$user_id, $tweet_id){
    preg_match_all("/@+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/i", $status, $matches);
    if($matches){
        $result = array_values($matches[1]);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :mention";

    foreach ($result as $trend) {
        if($stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql)){
            $stmt->execute(array(':mention' => $trend));
            $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
    }
    if($data->user_id != $user_id){
        Message::sendNotification($data->user_id, $user_id, $tweet_id, 'mention');
    }
}
```

And below is my sendNotication function

```
public function sendNotification($get_id, $user_id, $target, $type){
        $this->create('notification', array('notificationFor' => $get_id, 'notificationFrom' => $user_id, 'target' => $target, 'type' => $type, 'time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `Message` object so you can call its `sendNotification` method.

```
$msg = new Message()
$msg->sendNotification($data->user_id, $user_id, $tweet_id, 'mention');
```

The way you're calling it is only appropriate for a static method, which can't use `$this`.

Comment: how do I call sendNotification() through the object?

Comment: With the code in my answer. I assumed that it's a method of the same class.

Comment: They're in the `Message` class?

Comment: yes sir and this time Its now showing 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Tweet::sendNotification()'

Comment: That error means that the first function is in the `Tweet` class, not `Message`.

Comment: Without knowing the architecture of your classes, I have to do lots of guessing here. I've updated the answer with another guess.

Comment: will this help you understand better?  class Message extends User{
  function __construct($pdo){
   $this->pdo = $pdo;
  }

Comment: I don't know your class design at all. How am I supposed to know what the `User` class is. This is your code, you should know how they relate.

Comment: Why is a `Message` a subclass of `User`? Subclasses are supposed to represent "is a" relationships, how is a Message a kind of User?

Answer (score 0):

`$this` does not exist outside of instantiated class objects, you are showing a `function`, but no surrounding class, in your code examples. It must be that you're calling it from outside an object context.

```
?php

class Notification extends SomeClassWithACreateMethod
{
    public function sendNotification($get_id, $user_id, $target, $type){
        $this->create('notification', array('notificationFor' => $get_id, 
        'notificationFrom' => $user_id, 'target' => $target, 'type' => $type, 'time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
}
```

Try something more like that...keep in mind the `->create()` method you're calling needs to be part of this `Notification` class, too.

Comment: I think he just didn't show the class container, since `public function` won't even compile outside of a class.

Comment: Fair point, I didn't think about that. Cheers. I guess I should assume there's a create() function in that class, too. Heck, I don't know what to assume and what not to today. I think I have a cold.

Comment: And this doesn't really solve the problem, which is the way he's calling the method from the other method.

Comment: class Message extends User{
  function __construct($pdo){
   $this->pdo = $pdo;
  }